# How to add external jar files to grinder project

Tags: frameworks, jython, load-testing, grinder

I am new to Grinder load testing framework.

I recorded a grinder script using tcpproxy. And then I made some modifications which includes use of external jar files.

In eclipse using grinder plugin I added a dependency for those jar files.

But how do I setup similar stuff using command line - assuming I dont have eclipse available to me..

Do I have to add anything in grinder.properties ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add external jar file using properties file. You have to use grinder.jvm.classpath property. When you specify this property, it is added to class path every time grinder agent starts.

```
grinder.jvm.classpath=/lib/jyson-1.0.1.jar:/home/lib/my-loadtest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```