# Importing Jyson Jar into nGrinder

Tags: performance, jython, grinder

I'm trying to import the Jyson module to Grinder running on a remote machine. However, I see no clear guidance on how to accomplish this. Where does the jar file go? The Jyson zip I downloaded has a lib and src folder as well. I had read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455383/how-to-add-external-jar-files-to-grinder-project) link and understood what has to be added into the grinder.properties file, but where do the actual lib and src files go? If there is an already existing link that explains the same, please do link me to it.

Thanks for the all help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out how to do it. Created a src and lib folder via the UI and referenced it via code. Thanks!